# Jasypt hibernate 5 support?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jasypt

I'm upgrading a Spring project's Spring version`5.1.5.RELEASE` which requires an [upgrade to Hibernate 5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x).

I checked the jasypt [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt) but it doesn't seem to have a Hibernate 5 supported version yet.

What's the way to get around this? I don't even know if a Spring 5.x compatible jasypt is on its way.

**Edit:** I have already checkout out this [github repo](https://github.com/grelland/jasypt-hibernate5) and have opened an issue on it. I couldn't get it to compile.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It's already being used in my current project for string encryption etc. I want to keep using jasypt and upgrade to Spring 5.x

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work with an older version?

Comment: Because I see some test cases failing for me. I see `Time elapsed: 2.511 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor;)V` since the definition of nullSafeSet was updated in HIbernate class UserType but jasypt still references the older version.

Comment: https://github.com/grelland/jasypt-hibernate5

Comment: Yeah, there's an issue open on it. I have opened that, I couldn't get it to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jasypt hibernate support is officially available now, [here's](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt-hibernate5) a link to its maven repo.